# Is there a query that can add only business days , I used Date Add function but its still counting weekends?

Tags: sql, database

I'm setting up web-page to display Date for scheduling. Currently I'm using Date-add to add 5 business days, using Week , but it still takes into consideration of the weekend.

I've tried the following code below and it includes weekend

`select convert(varchar,dateadd(dw,5,getdate()),101)`

I'm expecting it to show 5 days from today not counting the weekend.

Comment: DateAdd (as it's name says), adds days. It is not *WeekDaysAdd*. Search this site for *add weekdays to date sql*. It would also help if you added a tag for the specific DBMS you're using when posting questions about SQL; you were shown a large hint when you added the SQL tag that told you that, and I'm not sure why you would ignore that hint.

Comment: This [Technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30877.t-sql-extending-dateadd-function-to-skip-weekend-days.aspx) discusses extending DATEADD to skip weekends, but as @KenWhite points out, this isn't an inherent function of DATEADD.

Comment: @jhelphenstine That worked ! Awesome thanks

Comment: What about weeks that have extended holiday weekends so there are only 4 days in the week?